# How to add filter on second table parameter while doing left join using criteriaquery

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteriaquery

I am stuck in a situation where I am not able to create a filter on left join between two table.
My query is something like this.

```
select count(*)   
  from orders o 
  left 
  join payments p 
    on o.id = p.o_id 
 where o.uid_id = 1 
   and p.name = "abc"
```

I am trying to do left join using criteria query. In criteria query.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Orders> query = cb.createQuery(Orders.class);
Root<Orders> ordersRoot = query.from(Orders.class);
Join<Orders, Payments> join = ordersRoot.join(JOIN_COLUMN, JoinType.LEFT);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.addAll(getPredicates(cb, ordersRoot)); //this method gives other predicates on order table
query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
query.select(ordersRoot).distinct(true);
TypedQuery<Orders> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Orders> list = query.getResultList();
```

This is my criteria Java code.
In this I have not added for this check.

orders and payments table has one to many relationship.

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN. Just sayin'

Comment: It is not, JoinType.LEFT is added

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query];` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;` This is an inner join, my friend.